# How to sync code from localhost to hosting?

Tags: synchronization, sublimetext3

I am using Sublime text 3 for coding, i am finding addon support sync between localhost and hosting. Can you give me a solution?
Thanks!

Comment: What kind of access to your hosting do you have?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.